# angular-material-rail-drawer compatible to Angular 13

Tags: angular, angular-material, angularjs-directive, npm-install

I want to use the Rail Drawer plugin in my project which is in Angular v13.

Running `npm i angular-material-rail-drawer` throws some errors, I tried all [previous versions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-rail-drawer?activeTab=versions), but nothing works.

Is there a way to use this plugin with Angular v13?

I tested it in my other project where I have Angular v15, and it works just fine.

Is there any version of `angular-material-rail-drawer` compatible with Angular v13?

Comment: Could you provide us further information (error message, typescript version, plugin version..)

Comment: I wanted to use the Rail Drawer plugin in my Angular ^13.1.3 project, but there is no compatible version. so, I just made use of this library (https://github.com/Jordan-Hall/angular-material-rail-drawer-plugin/tree/master/projects/angular-material-rail-drawer/src/lib) as my own directive.

Comment: I've also found a GitHub issue related to that topic https://github.com/angular/components/issues/1728

Comment: please share with us the error you get

Comment: `This application depends upon a library published using Angular version 15.0.4, which requires Angular version 14.0.0 or newer to work correctly.`

Comment: there were lots of errors about dependencies `unable to resolve dependency tree`